# Selective decompression, ommitting the existing absolute folder structure, of tar to a directory

Tags: linux, docker, gzip, tar

Say the `example.tar.gz` archive contains the following:

```
volumes/wordpress/a
volumes/wordpress/.b
volumes/wordpress/c/d
volumes/service2/a
volumes/service2/.b
volumes/service3/c/d
volumes/service3/a
volumes/service3/.b
volumes/service3/c/d
```

I want to extract the contents of `volumes/wordpress` of the archive to `/var/www/html` directory on the host (which already exists and cannot be removed), to end up with:

```
/var/www/html/a
/var/www/html/.b
/var/www/html/c/d
```

I have no way of reformating the tar file.

What I have tried:

- `gunzip -c example.tar.gz | tar -C /var/www/html -xf - volumes/wordpress`

  but this creates `/var/www/html/volumes/wordpress/...`
- `gunzip -c example.tar.gz | bash -c 'tar -C /tmp -xf - volumes/wordpress && mv /tmp/volumes/wordpress/* /var/www/html'`

  but this skips the `.b` file
- `gunzip -c example.tar.gz | bash -c 'tar -C /tmp -xf - volumes/wordpress && rsync -a --remove-source-files /tmp/volumes/wordpress/ /var/www/html/'`

  but rsync does not exist in the context of a docker container

Note, because I don't think it is relevant to this question I skipped out on Docker related specifics but in case useful, the commands I am running are of this format:

- `gunzip ... | docker-compose run --rm wordpress tar ...`
  This allows the wordpress container to be defined in docker-compose yml (hence why I state I cannot remove `/var/www/html/`, as it is mounted as a volume)

*Edit* It turned out that I ended up finding a satisfactory (although hacky) solution to my problem and it WAS Docker specific (so edited question to include Docker tag). I will supply hacky answer as an answer to the question. Still interested in a non Docker related answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remount the already defined (by docker-compose.yml) volume, `my-volume` to a docker-compose run of `my-service`, but in this case mapped to a second containerized directory, where tar would output its contents.

e.g.

`gunzip -c example.tar.gz | docker-compose run --rm -v my-volume:/volumes/wordpress my-service tar -C / -xf - volumes/wordpress`